# Google Analytics Metro Filter Billings MT

Tags: php, web, google-analytics-api

In my options array I am trying to filter on the metro area "Billings MT" using `'filters'=>'ga:metro==Billings, MT'`.

However it comes back with the error `"code":400,"message":"Invalid value 'ga:metro==Billings, MT' for filters parameter."`

I've tried `'filters'=>'ga:metro==Billings MT'` but that doesn't return results.

From the analytics dashboard on `analytics.google.com` the metro name is "Billings, MT"

Has anyone else run into this problem?

Comment: Have you tried `ga:city==Billings`? I think `ga:metro` expects the DMA name, of which I am unfamiliar with.

Comment: One thing can be done. Find out the possible values of ga:metro without passing any filter to the query.

Comment: @nyuen ga:city==Billings also returns no results.

Comment: @dikesh when I don't pass any filter values, the API comes back with the name `Billings, MT` but that value in the filter generates the original error. I believe it's a problem with the comma. The API interprets the comma as a delimiter for another filter, not the state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it because of comma.

Try escaping it like `'ga:metro==Billings\, MT'`. It should work.

Comment: Great solution, thank you, just need to take out the \ when displaying the name